# Views contextual display based on taxonomy for no value

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type that has a name field and a taxonomy field that contains cities. I want the view to display by default the city as title and the message "nobody lives in city X" for each of the cities, i.e. "Nobody lives in New York" before I create any content. Once I create a person and select New York, it should display "John lives in New York". I assume this involves contextual filters and maybe relationship with the taxonomy entity, but I couldn't make it work.

Any help?

Comment: I'm confused about what type of Views you want to create, and where do you want to change the display, on content pages, views, users? Can you edit your question and clarify the structure and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my content type only has a text field for the name of the person and a taxonomy field for the cities. All I want to see by default is a list of all Cities as titles, each with a summary saying that there are no people in this city, but I want the message to be contextual, i.e. Title: Tokyo, message 'Nobody lives in Tokyo'. Once I add content for the content type, the message should change with the people's name I am adding through the content type. Please let me know if it makes more sense. Thank you

Comment: I'm still confused what goes where. Can you update the question with a nice structure, screenshot it if you don't want to write out categories, CTs and their fields, Views and what they should do, what the content page should show, what Views page should show... Show an example of what the Views results you want to see. I understand the Contextual text message, but where should it be? Why would you have City and next to it that message? On content or views?